# Fetch the value of variable inside variable in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In the JSR Sampler I am assigning the value of a String I create i.e., SFDC_Prouct_1 in list. for e.g.,
list=SFDCProduct_5

Here SFDCProduct_5 is already a variable which has XML elements. Now I am trying to place a http request and in the payload I want to inject the value of SFDCProduct_5 . But I have to write ${list}, as list has the value of SFDCProduct_5 .

I tried ${${list}}, but thats not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show more of your code so thatwe can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question you need to wrap your `${list}` into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) like

```
${__eval(${list})}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Evaluate Nested Variable]

See [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) article for more information if needed.

Comment: Thank you. Will definitely try this.

Answer (score 1):

In JSR223 Sampler you can get the nested variable using `vars.get`

```
 vars.get(vars.get("list"));
```

Comment: Thank you. :) I just used an extractor but will try this as well. This is more neat way.

Comment: Hi @user7294900. Like your dp. I observed most my questions are answered by you which are mostly correct. Do you work for stack overflow or just a user?

Comment: @Apu just a user, you can upvote my answer if it helped